# How to fix this Dash background distortion?

Tags: unity, 13.04

I downloaded Ubuntu 13.04 and chose to try it first. This mess of shapes and colours is what I got to see:

[image: visual depiction of the glitch]

Apparently the Dash's background is being distorted.